# How to get the Get Windows 10 apps icon runiing on my taskbar

Tags: windows-7, windows

Hi I want to run windows 10 apps on my taskbar.But when I run the script that appraisal my computer, I get nothing from the command prompt script.

The script is

`C:\Temp>REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFl
ags\UpgradeExperienceIndicators" /v UpgEx   | findstr UpgEx  if "0" == "0" GOTO
RunGWX  reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlag
s\Appraiser" /v UtcOnetimeSend /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f  schtasks /run /TN "\Microso
ft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser"  :CompatChe
ckRunning  schtasks /query /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Micros
oft Compatibility Appraiser"  schtasks /query /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Applicatio
n Experience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser"   | findstr Ready  if NOT "0" ==
 "0" ping localhost   1>nul  & goto :CompatCheckRunning  :RunGWX  schtasks /run
/TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Setup\gwx\refreshgwxconfig"`

My Result is

`FINDSTR: Cannot open if
FINDSTR: Cannot open NOT
FINDSTR: Cannot open 0
FINDSTR: Cannot open ==
FINDSTR: Cannot open if
FINDSTR: Cannot open 0
FINDSTR: Cannot open 0
FINDSTR: Cannot open ping
FINDSTR: Cannot open ==
FINDSTR: Cannot open localhost
FINDSTR: Cannot open 0
FINDSTR: Cannot open GOTO
FINDSTR: Cannot open RunGWX
FINDSTR: Cannot open reg
FINDSTR: Cannot open add
FINDSTR: Cannot open HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompat
Flags\Appraiser
FINDSTR: Cannot open /v
FINDSTR: Cannot open UtcOnetimeSend
FINDSTR: Cannot open /t
FINDSTR: Cannot open REG_DWORD
FINDSTR: Cannot open /d
FINDSTR: Cannot open 1
FINDSTR: Cannot open /f
FINDSTR: Cannot open schtasks
FINDSTR: Cannot open /run
FINDSTR: Cannot open /TN
FINDSTR: Cannot open \Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compati
bility Appraiser
FINDSTR: Cannot open :CompatCheckRunning
FINDSTR: Cannot open schtasks
FINDSTR: Cannot open /query
FINDSTR: Cannot open /TN
FINDSTR: Cannot open \Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compati
bility Appraiser
FINDSTR: Cannot open schtasks
FINDSTR: Cannot open /query
FINDSTR: Cannot open /TN
FINDSTR: Cannot open \Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compati
bility Appraiser
The system cannot find the batch label specified - CompatCheckRunning`

## Can Someone explain it to me?

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: **carefully** read the answer in the linked duplicate. Paste the text for the script **into a file as indicated**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you got your script from here:
http://techdows.com/2015/06/how-to-enable-get-windows-10-app-icon-windows-7-or-8-1-taskbar.html

Bodging your registry to get the app will only cause you problems.

If you want to be able to install windows 10, you need a minimum number of installed patches on your machine.  These are:

- KB3035583
- KB2952664

You will also need to ensure you are running windows 7 SP1

If you really must bodge your registry, the article above includes a link to a CMD file which will do the registry changes for you... all you need to do is save the .cmd file, disable your AV, right click & run as administrtator... then reenable your AV and run windows updates.